# How can I get the last item in a BTreeMap?

Tags: rust, b-tree

If you have a sorted map of key/value pairs (or just keys), one of the obvious operations is to get the first or last pair (or key).

C++'s [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)  has `front()` and `back()` for this purpose. [`std::map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) doesn't, but `*map.begin()` and `*map.rbegin()` (reverse iterator) work for this (assuming one knows the map is not empty).

In Rust, getting the first element of a map seems to require `map.iter().next().unwrap()` — ugly, but perhaps justified considering some error checking is needed.

How can we get the last element? By stepping over all elements: `map.iter().last().unwrap()`?

I see that there is [`Iterator::rev()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.rev), so is `map.iter().rev().next().unwrap()` a reasonable alternative?

Comment: Why the unwrap? Can you structure the code so that you use the presence (or non-) of the back value in a conditional?

Comment: Good point; I ended up using `.unwrap_or(0)` for this use-case. For another I needed to know first that there was exactly one element, hence `map.iter().next().unwrap()` — a bit unwieldy way of getting the only element!

Comment: The `first()` and `last()` methods are coming soon: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/62924

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/alloc/collections/btree_map/struct.BTreeMap.html#method.last_entry

Answer (score 23):

[`btree_map::Iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/btree_map/struct.Iter.html), which is returned by `BTreeMap::iter()`, implements [`DoubleEndedIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.DoubleEndedIterator.html), so indeed, either the approach with `rev()` would work or [you can use the `next_back()` method directly](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3f47322175556101ba43caab82db27ad):

```
let (key, value) = map.iter().next_back().unwrap();
```

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31690#issuecomment-184445033

A dedicated method would improve discoverability, but you can do:

```
let map: BTreeMap<K, V> = ...;
let min = map.iter().next();
let max = map.iter().next_back();
```

and the same for BTreeSet.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Iterator::rev`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.rev) method requires that `Self` implements [`DoubleEndedIterator`](https://ebarnard.github.io/2019-06-03-rust-smaller-trait-implementers-docs/std/iter/trait.DoubleEndedIterator.html), so it should always be an optimized and correct choice for your use case.

```rust
fn rev(self) -> Rev<Self>
where
    Self: DoubleEndedIterator,
```